# Storing SQL return select statement into variable returns wrong value

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, select

So I am trying to return my Select statement into a variable. It is working, however it is returning the wrong value...

In most cases it will return the value of -7 columns than what it should be. I thought it was my code, so I tried it in SQL server manager without parameters and got nearly the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my select statement (if you don't want to go through the code):

```
"SELECT [Item #] FROM dbo.[" + cmbJobName.Text + "] WHERE [Manufacturer] LIKE @Manufacturer AND [Mill Location] LIKE @MillLocation AND [Product Description] LIKE @ProductDescription AND [Weld Seam Type] LIKE @WeldSeamType AND [Outer Dimension] LIKE @OuterDimension AND [Wall Thickness] LIKE @WallThickness AND [Coating] LIKE @Coating AND [Grade] LIKE @Grade AND [Heat] LIKE @Heat AND [ANSI/ASME] LIKE @ANSIASME AND [Purchase Order] LIKE @PurchaseOrder AND [Standard] LIKE @Standard AND [Notes] LIKE @Notes";
```

And Here is my code:

```
         try
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connection.MTRDataBaseConn))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Item #] FROM dbo.[" + cmbJobName.Text + "] WHERE [Manufacturer] LIKE @Manufacturer AND [Mill Location] LIKE @MillLocation AND [Product Description] LIKE @ProductDescription AND [Weld Seam Type] LIKE @WeldSeamType AND [Outer Dimension] LIKE @OuterDimension AND [Wall Thickness] LIKE @WallThickness AND [Coating] LIKE @Coating AND [Grade] LIKE @Grade AND [Heat] LIKE @Heat AND [ANSI/ASME] LIKE @ANSIASME AND [Purchase Order] LIKE @PurchaseOrder AND [Standard] LIKE @Standard AND [Notes] LIKE @Notes";

                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    SqlParameter pManufactuter = new SqlParameter("@Manufacturer", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    SqlParameter pMillLocation = new SqlParameter("@MillLocation", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    SqlParameter pProductDescription = new SqlParameter("@ProductDescription", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    SqlParameter pWeldSeamType = new SqlParameter("@WeldSeamType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    SqlParameter pOuterDimension = new SqlParameter("@OuterDimension", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    SqlParameter pWallThickness = new SqlParameter("@WallThickness", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    SqlParameter pCoating = new SqlParameter("@Coating", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    SqlParameter pGrade = new SqlParameter("@Grade", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    SqlParameter pHeat = new SqlParameter("@Heat", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    SqlParameter pAnsiAsme = new SqlParameter("@ANSIASME", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    SqlParameter pPurchaseOrder = new SqlParameter("@PurchaseOrder", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    SqlParameter pStandard = new SqlParameter("@Standard", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    SqlParameter pNotes = new SqlParameter("@Notes", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);

                    pManufactuter.Value = cmbManufacturer.Text;
                    pMillLocation.Value = cmbMillLocation.Text;
                    pProductDescription.Value = cmbProductDescription.Text;
                    pWeldSeamType.Value = cmbWeldSeamType.Text;
                    pOuterDimension.Value = cmbOuterDimension.Text;
                    pWallThickness.Value = cmbWallThickness.Text;
                    pCoating.Value = cmbCoating.Text;
                    pGrade.Value = cmbGrade.Text;
                    pHeat.Value = txtHeat.Text;
                    pAnsiAsme.Value = cmbANSI.Text;
                    pPurchaseOrder.Value = txtPurchaseOrder.Text;
                    pStandard.Value = cmbStandard.Text;
                    pNotes.Value = txtNotes.Text;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(pManufactuter);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(pMillLocation);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(pProductDescription);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(pWeldSeamType);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(pOuterDimension);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(pWallThickness);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(pCoating);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(pGrade);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(pHeat);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(pAnsiAsme);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(pPurchaseOrder);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(pStandard);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(pNotes);

                    int result = ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar());

                    txtReturnFromSelect.Text = result.ToString();

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                //catch error
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

**NOTE**

The database currently just consists of numbers and text strings with no spaces for testing purposes. For instance, I created one row with just the word "foo" and another row with just the word "bar" not a single character of "foo" and "bar" are in any other rows of the database, but it returned the ID -5 rows from the inputs Which these rows **ONLY** contained numbers. This happens in both my SQL query and the application.

**UPDATE:**

I don't know what the issue was, but I dropped the tables and remade them with the same query and now have no problems... maybe a fluke when creating the tables initially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute a statement and return multiple rows, use `ExecuteReader`.

```
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader["Column1Name"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(reader["Column2Name"].ToString());
}
```

If you do want to return just the first value from the first column then you are correct to use `ExecuteScalar`.  However, your 2nd execute statement (execute non query) isn't needed.

If ExecuteScalar is right but the value you are getting back is incorrect - your query or data is wrong.  Build the query directly in SQL Server management Studio first to make sure it's working correctly, then codify it.

Comment: I did and it returned the same value... While looking at the query I don't see an issue with it.

Comment: Can you replicate your issue on http://sqlfiddle.com/ with some fake data?

Comment: I got it to work yesterday with the above answer, however sqlfiddle.com crashes my browsers every time I use it at work for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Your sql statement could return more than one record given the code so doing an ExecuteScalar doesn't make sense as it only returns a single value back (the first column first row) from the database. You are better off opening a data reader or populating a dataset and reading the data from there.

Comment: If you want to execute a statement and return multiple rows, use `ExecuteReader`.

Comment: I would like it to return more than one (using an if statement I can add an error stating an existing record exists) But in this case there are no records that match each other. in which case, will store the returned column/row to a variable.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your requirement. Are you just checking for existence of a record matching your criteria?

Comment: I am trying to use a select statement and find the Auto Incremented ID Number Assigned to the row based on the exact criteria entered in text boxes then return that ID # into a variable in my program. However, If there are more than one, I will put an if statement into it to alert the user there are duplicate entries.

Comment: So to do this, I would load a dataset from the query and then grab the first record and check the record count to determine if you needed to present a warning.

Comment: I'll give it a try, I'm about to get off work, I'll post back tomorrow on what I came up with.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the data?  Is there possibly an unescaped illegal character in the data where it stops?

Comment: Yes, in this case it's just numbers and text strings with no spaces for testing purposes. For instance, I created one row with just the word "foo" and another row with just the word "bar" not a single character of "foo" and "bar" are in any other rows of the database, but it returned the ID -5 rows from the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

i was just thinking...  dont you need % in the like commands!!!  One on each side you of the string you want similar--%  where something is like "%word%"??????

Comment: To be more specific:  ...WHERE [Manufacturer] LIKE  %@Manufacturer% AND